# Record after record calculation in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I would like to perform the following task:
Assume that I have ordered sequence of records as in the given example below

timestamp event

10:00 A

10:01 B

10:05 A

10:09 A

10:10 B

A "good" sequence of events is A->B. If there is an A that do not followed by B, before there is another A, it is regarded as "Bad" sequence. I want to count good/bad events.
To my opinion, it can be targeted as record after record calculation (i.e any A record is given by 1 indicator. if B record comes right after an A record the indicator is 1, otherwise 0).
Is there a way to implement it in pig without any UDF?
If not, can someone suggest how to write a python one ?

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: If A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,B,A,A is a sequence then what will you expect in your output?

Comment: This problem requires sequential access to each data record, which violates the map reduce requirement of needing to be able to process records independently. You probably could solve this with map reduce by breaking apart the file into chunks and writing a customer InputFormatter to handle each chunk sequentially... I don't know a simple built in way in pig to do this though (plus you'd need to handle the first/last record of each chunk specially).